# Outlook 365 webmail client

Tags: office-365, outlook-on-the-web

Is it just me, or is the text editor of the webmail interface at outlook.office.com  really buggy when it comes to setting fonts?  I am unable to select a full paragraph, or select just a sentence, and change its font face or size via the popup menu.  The size/face I choose from the popup menu's dropdowns are not being applied to the selected text.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the https://outlook.office365.com using Firefox 99.0 (64-bit) without any problem.

To solve this kind of issue I would suggest you try it with another browser like Firefox, chrome or opera. (Sometimes the browser itself is the problem especially for internet explorer).

Comment: I think it might sometimes get confused when there's more than one font face or size in use in the selection.  Thanks for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I've used https://outlook.office365.com/owa/ with Chrome on Windows 10 for several years. Outlook on the web is ride with bugs and is very sluggish, but I haven't encountered any issues when applying fonts to text, which I've done a fair amount of time.